# What HTTP status code to use for 'account required' pages?

Tags: http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, google-search-console

I run a site where some pages require a free account to access. I'm noticing a large number of soft 404s in Webmaster Tools coming from these pages. What is the correct status code to pass for these pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that a '403: Forbidden' status code would be the most acceptible in this situation. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) says

> "A typical request that may receive a 403 Forbidden response is a GET
>   for a web page, performed by a web browser to retrieve the page for
>   display to a user in a browser window. The web server may return a 403
>   Forbidden status for other types of requests as well."